# Chatterbot ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy' )

Tags: python, spacy, chatterbot, modulenotfounderror

I have been trying to make a chatbot using chatterbot but I am getting this error(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'). Please can someone tell me what is going wrong with the code

```
import chatterbot_corpus

from chatterbot import ChatBot

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer



my_bot = ChatBot(name="PyBot", read_only=True, logic_adapters= 
 ["chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation", "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"])

trainer = ListTrainer(my_bot)

talk = ["hi there" , 
    "hello !",
    "how are you?",
    "how do you do ?",
    "i\'m fine how about you?"
    ]

for iteam in (talk):  
    trainer.train(iteam)

while True:                        
    user = str(input("You: "))                                        
    responce = my_bot.get_response(user) 
    print("Bot: " + str(responce))
```

Comment: Follow https://spacy.io/usage instructions to install spaCy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like spacy is required for your imported module to work. Looking at the [git](https://github.com/gunthercox/chatterbot-corpus/issues/206) for the module I found this guide to solve the issue:

You can either run the following in your command prompt/Terminal:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Or if you are using anaconda inside there Terminal for your environment

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Comment: @Dcoder no problem don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.